# PHP Curl does not work on localhost?

Tags: php, curl, localhost

I am using MAMP Pro 1.9.4 on Mac OSX
In `phpinfo()` I see curl is enabled

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.20.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS   No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN Yes
IPv6    Yes
Largefile   Yes
NTLM    Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL Yes
SSPI    No
krb4    No
libz    Yes
CharConv    No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    i386-apple-darwin8.11.1
SSL Version OpenSSL/0.9.7l
ZLib Version    1.2.3
```

My script is to geocode lat long from Google apis.
It works online on my hosting providers server but not on localhost.. WHY??

```
$latlng = "44.3585230889,8.57745766643";
$lang = "it";
$geocodeURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$latlng&sensor=false&language=$lang";

$ch = curl_init($geocodeURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($httpCode == 200) {
    $geocode = json_decode($result);

    $location   = $geocode->results[0]->address_components[0]->long_name;
    $city       = $geocode->results[0]->address_components[1]->long_name; 
    $province   = $geocode->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name; 
    $region     = $geocode->results[0]->address_components[3]->long_name;
    $country    = $geocode->results[0]->address_components[4]->long_name;

    $geo_status = $geocode->status;     
    $geo_str    = "$location, $city, $province, $region, $country";
} else {
    $geo_status = "HTTP_FAIL_$httpCode";
    $geo_str    = "Failed: $geo_status";
}
```

Comment: What $httpCode are you receiving?

Comment: mmm when I remove the CURLOPT_PROXY option I get $httpCode = 0

Comment: PHP and Apache logs don't give me anything...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably a firewall issue. Curl by default tries to use port 1080, which is probably not open on your localhost / router / ISP.

Comment: curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 8089);

Comment: Ok you where right Dan I had this Firewall rule to block any `httpd` connections. After disabling this everything worked.

Comment: You need to check if curl is enabled with phpinfo() function. if it's enabled then you have to disable SSL with code. check the "Sebass van Bodel" answer on this page.

Answer (score 48):

It's not about proxy, it's about how to use googleapis.

Add `CURLOPT_SSL_ on` your code and set them into `false`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: Watchout that you're not sending any sensitive data; turning off SSL verification like this can leave you open to hackers: http://ademar.name/blog/2006/04/curl-ssl-certificate-problem-v.html

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I recently worked on a project using cURL for the first time and everything was working perfect on my local installation, but it was simply not working on the final computer where I was hosting it. Spent about 5 hours trying everything I could think of before finding this.

Comment: Easiest answer to implement and works. Just make sure you remove it for production.

Comment: @arbo77 You rocks buddy..Thank you so much +1000

Answer (score 7):

On a local server (eg XAMPP) with a self-signed certificate you must use:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

> **Note**: Despite being unsafe for testing environments it solves the problem.
> Remember to activate for production servers !!!

Comment: I tried setting `CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST`, `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` but this was the only one needed to work on MAMP. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may need to set the SSL version and the matching Cipher for `$ch`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

For the exact parameters you can pass to `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` see:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Also the following can display errors related to SSL versions being used to help find exact version conflict you have:

```
$error = curl_error($ch);
echo $error;
```

More on this command: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a proxy, you could try adding `CURLOPT_PROXY`, for example (assuming your proxy is on 192.168.1.2 port 3128):

```
$ch = curl_init($geocodeURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "192.168.1.2:3128");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you are behind a proxy, you need to find out your proxy detail and replace the `192.168.1.2:3128` part :)

Answer (score 1):

In MAMP, if you are getting errors when connecting to HTTPS hosts, just set this option:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);

The equivalent by command line is:

curl -k -ssl3 https://www.your-secure-host.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have the `curl` binary installed?  You can have the `curl` library installed with PHP without actually having the `curl` binary on your system.  Drop to a shell prompt and type `curl`.  (If it's standard on OSX then please forgive my ignorance - I'm not a Mac guy)

Answer (score 0):

If your OS dont provide cacert.pem file to your local server for SSL certificate validation, you can download it and specify it in php.ini

[cacert.pem](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html)

php.ini:

```
[openssl]
; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may still
; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
; option.
openssl.cafile=C:\wamp64\cacert.pem
```