# Apache / PHP - curl module not properly executed

Tags: php, curl, apache2, config, modx

I have set up an Apache2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and loaded the PHP module. I want to execute following php script:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppaidapplications/genre=36/limit=15/json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200000);
$string = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($string,true);
foreach($arr['feed']['entry'] as $val)
{
$var = $val['link']['0']['attributes']['href'];
echo $var;
}
```

I get this error message when I load it with my CMS (MODX)

```
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\webserver\www\site1\core\cache\includes\elements\modsnippet\4.include.cache.php on line 15
```

I guess I have configured something wrong either in the apache: httpd.conf or in the php.ini since on another webserver which was not set by me the script is running fine.

phpinfo tells me  that curl is enabled (PHP Version 5.4.17)

```
curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.30.0
Age     3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   Yes
IDN     No
IPv6    Yes
Largefile   Yes
NTLM    Yes
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL     Yes
SSPI    Yes
krb4    No
libz    Yes
CharConv    No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    i386-pc-win32
SSL Version     OpenSSL/0.9.8y
ZLib Version    1.2.7
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.2
```

On the webserver where the script is running I am running an older PHP version (PHP Version 5.2.17). Here phpinfo sais:

```
curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/1.0.0i zlib/1.2.5
```

In my php.ini is writen the following pointing to the php_curl.dll

```
extension="c:\webserver\php\ext\php_curl.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding following to the script

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

solution found here:
[PHP Curl does not work on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419747/php-curl-does-not-work-on-localhost?rq=1)