# Fetching a URL via CURL in PHP results in a Plesk error page

Tags: php, curl, plesk

I have a strange problem which may or may not be tied to Plesk. This PHP script intends to fetch a page on the same server when executed on the same domain e.g. http://quotationsbook.com/sometestpage.php

```
<?php
error_reporting('E_ALL');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
function curlFileGetContents($urlreq) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlreq);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $request_result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch))
        $response = 0;
    else
        $response = $request_result;
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
    }
$url = 'http://quotationsbook.com';
$data = curlFileGetContents($url);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

However, it does not fetch the page requested, it always fetches a Plesk error page.

In terms of the PHP var allow_url_fopen it is set to On.

The problem only occurs for the same domain where the code is hosted, not for other domains. i.e. it only occurs on http://quotationsbook.com where what I'm trying to fetch is under http://quotationsbook.com/*, it does not occur when I try to fetch say, http://google.com

Comment: What's the error page say?

Comment: This is the response I see when I curl http://quotationsbook.com above:

http://chopapp.com/#vro2vmck

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is actually in your last paragraph.

> The problem only occurs for the same domain where the code is hosted,
>   not for other domains. i.e. it only occurs on
>   http://quotationsbook.com where what I'm trying to fetch is under
>   http://quotationsbook.com/*, it does not occur when I try to fetch
>   say, http://google.com

That is your clue.

I must pose a question and that is why use CURL if you are on the same server? What are you trying to accomplish? There are probably better solutions out there than using CURL.

Assuming you need to use CURL, it's likely a firewall or other security issue. Make sure the port being accessed is open and not blocked.

See [PHP Curl does not work on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419747/php-curl-does-not-work-on-localhost)